# Mini USB receptacle versus proper PCB layout

Tags: pcb, usb, pcb-design

While routing my CY7C68013A based PCB I just realized that regular USB B receptacle and mini USB equivalent have D+ and D- effectively swapped.

It seems that the chip was prepared for regular size receptacle (DP is on the left if looking towards the chip), while for mini USB I have to route one of the tracks under the receptacle.

Is it really like this, or did I mess something up? How am I suppose to keep the tracks impedance and length constraints, while one of the tracks needs to go a different way, around the receptacle pads?

Comment: Most likely getting impedance and length matching perfect on those lines wont make that big of a difference, especially if the lengths aren't too different. I would like to see what a "professional" has to say though.

Comment: Which encapsulation (package) are you using?

Comment: For the connector? It's something like this: 
http://www.farnell.com/cad/452550.pdf

The chip itself is TQFP-100 version.

Comment: Be careful when you're laying out this part.  Do not run traces underneath, between the mounting lugs, because the metal is sharp and can scratch through the solder mask.

Comment: The USB Spec is *Extremely* conservative. I've done some horrible things to USB cables, and still managed to run full USB 2.0 over them.

Comment: Also, do you really need a USB-B-mini? The layout for a USB-B full-size is very clean.

Comment: Indeed, and that's exactly what I did - I'm using full size USB, it's an experiment after all. I had no time to finish this PCB yet, unfortunately, so I'm not able to share the results.

Comment: If you have to swap the position of traces, can you use a 0 ohm jumper resistor instead of vias?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've noticed the same problem when routing boards with the FTDI FT232 chips. Here's what the CY7C68013A datasheet says about routing those signals:

> - DPLUS and DMINUS trace lengths should be kept to within  2 mm of each other in length, with preferred length of 20 to  30 mm.
> - Maintain a solid ground plane under the DPLUS and DMINUS  traces. Do not allow the plane to split under these traces.
> - Do not place vias on the DPLUS or DMINUS trace routing.
> - Isolate the DPLUS and DMINUS traces from all other signal  traces by no less than 10 mm.

I would suggest the zig-zag method, but only if it that little detour around the pin added more than 2 mm to the trace length.

Comment: FT232 chips are full-speed devices, running at a maximum of 12 Mbit/s.  The Cypress chip referenced is a USB 2.0 High-speed device, which can do up to 480 Mbit/s.  The routing requirements are similar (at least they're both using differential signals), but they won't be identical.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear that those recommendations are from the datasheet for the CY7C68013A that the OP is using. I don't think the FT232 datasheet has such strict requirements, as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that D- and D+ are swapped? I checked the [USB2 specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_20_021411.zip). ECN 1 describes the miniB connector, and I see the same order for the regular and the mini: Vbus, D-, D+, Ground.

If the connections *are* swapped, can't you add a few zigzags in the shorter trace to make it as long as the other? (I don't think it is really necessary, but it might give you some rest :-))

[image]

Comment: Pins appear swapped at the PCB level, not at the plug level, due to different receptacle geometry - unless I've messed it up :)

Comment: @Czajnik, could it be that it's intended to be mounted on the bottom of the board and someone is just tricking it?

Comment: I guess not, as PCBs with components on one side are obviously cheaper to manufacture. The receptacle I want to use is a standard, commonly used component. Perhaps the perfect impedance and length match is not as critical as I think?

Answer (score 1):

This one docs states that the prefered mounting for microusb-b is on the underside.
http://portal.fciconnect.com/Comergent//fci/drawing/10103593.pdf

I also had the problem when mounted on the topside that D+ D- would not line up.
Had to put the chip below the connector instead and run the traces between shield pins.